# Scala / Akka: NullPointerException on master actor?

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, akka

I'm very new to Akka for Scala and I'm getting an error message, which I don't understand. My code basically runs an evolutionary algorithm. For each new individual that is created during one generation it has to be evaluated. The evaluation of those individuals is what I'd like to parallelize (and in the long term I'd like to do that on a cluster). For implementing that I've completely oriented my code towards the Getting Started Tutorial on the Akka website. The code looks as follows:

```
object Configuration {

sealed trait Message
case object Broadcast extends Message
case class Work(inds:ArrayBuffer[Individual]) extends Message
case class Result(result:ArrayBuffer[Individual]) extends Message
case class NewIndividuals(inds:ArrayBuffer[Individual]) extends Message

class Worker extends Actor {

    val id = (Math.random * 100).asInstanceOf[Int]

    def receive = {
        case Work(inds) =>
            sender ! Result(geneticOperation(inds)) // perform the work
    }

    private def geneticOperation(inds:ArrayBuffer[Individual]) = {
        for(child <- inds) {
            child.mutate
            child.evaluate
            println(id + ": I've evaluated one.")
        }
        println("\n")
        inds
    }

}

class Master(nrOfWorkers:Int, nrOfMessages:Int, oldInds:ArrayBuffer[Individual], listener:ActorRef)
    extends Actor {

    var inds:ArrayBuffer[Individual] = _ 
    var nrOfResults:Int = _
    val start:Long = System.currentTimeMillis

    val workerRouter = context.actorOf(
            Props[Worker].withRouter(RoundRobinRouter(nrOfWorkers)), name = "workerRouter")

    def receive = {
        case Broadcast =>
            var workOn = new ArrayBuffer[Individual]    
            for(i <- 0 until nrOfMessages)
                workOn += oldInds(i)
            oldInds.trimStart(nrOfMessages)
            workerRouter ! Work(workOn)
        case Result(newInds) =>
            inds ++= newInds
            nrOfResults += 1
            println(nrOfResults)
            if(nrOfResults == nrOfMessages) {
                listener ! NewIndividuals(inds)
                context.stop(self)
            }
    }

}

class Listener extends Actor {
    def receive = {
        case NewIndividuals(inds) =>
            Configuration.environment(inds)
            context.system.shutdown()
    }
}

var d = Parameter.N_DROPLET_TYPE-2

  /** Apply genetic operators (recombination, mutation) on the population 
   * during the current generation.
   *  @param g Current generation.
   */
def apply(g:Int) {
    var children = Population.recombinate   // create offspring
    calculate(Parameter.NODES,(Parameter.L / Parameter.NODES),children)
}

def calculate(nrOfWorkers:Int, nrOfMessages:Int, inds:ArrayBuffer[Individual]) {
    val system = ActorSystem("GeneticOperations")
    val listener = system.actorOf(Props[Listener], name="listener")
    val master = system.actorOf(Props(new Master(
            nrOfWorkers,nrOfMessages,inds,listener)),
            name="master")
    master ! Broadcast
}

    private def environment(children:ArrayBuffer[Individual]) {
      if(Parameter.NEUTRAL) {       // if neutral evolution no selection pressure
          Population.neutralEvolution(children)
          writeDiversity
      }
      else Population.select(children)
      writeAllToEvoPath
}
```

When I run it I get the following output:

```
ID akka
Population setup complete.
Evolution: Gen 1
Gen 2
Gen 3
Gen 4
Gen 5
Gen 6
Gen 7
Gen 8
Gen 9


107 seconds elapsed.
79: I've evaluated one.
67: I've evaluated one.
89: I've evaluated one.
56: I've evaluated one.
17: I've evaluated one.
55: I've evaluated one.
77: I've evaluated one.
15: I've evaluated one.
57: I've evaluated one.
79: I've evaluated one.


[ERROR] [05/03/2012 12:15:01.864] [GeneticOperations-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] [akka://GeneticOperations/user/master] null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at framework.Configuration$Master$$anonfun$receive$2.apply(Configuration.scala:75)
at framework.Configuration$Master$$anonfun$receive$2.apply(Configuration.scala:67)
at akka.actor.Actor$class.apply(Actor.scala:311)
at framework.Configuration$Master.apply(Configuration.scala:57)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:619)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:196)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:178)
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$MailboxExecutionTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:505)
at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:259)
at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:974)
at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1478)
at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)

55: I've evaluated one.


[ERROR] [05/03/2012 12:15:04.339] [GeneticOperations-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://GeneticOperations/user/master] null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at framework.Configuration$Master$$anonfun$receive$2.apply(Configuration.scala:75)
at framework.Configuration$Master$$anonfun$receive$2.apply(Configuration.scala:67)
at akka.actor.Actor$class.apply(Actor.scala:311)
at framework.Configuration$Master.apply(Configuration.scala:57)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:619)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:196)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:178)
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$MailboxExecutionTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:505)
at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:259)
at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:974)
at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1478)
at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
```

(and so forth)

For each generation (gen) it should do the evaluations but instead, it seems that my code is not waiting for the Master Actor to get the results and just carries on. The error messages look to me like there is a NullPointerException on the Master? But I don't get why that should happen. The Akka tutorial claims that it waits until the Master has all the results from the Workers back (which is what I want to have).

Anything that helps would be greatly appreciated! (Please note that I am really a total beginner with Akka.)

**Update:**

1) framework.Configuration$Master$$anonfun$receive$2.apply(Configuration.scala:75): 
inds ++= newInds (in Master, receive, case Result)

2) The variables in Parameter are just integers, in this case NODES = 4, L = 8

Comment: Would have really helped if you'd actually include what code is at: framework.Configuration$Master$$anonfun$receive$2.apply(Configuration.scala:75)

Comment: Is it: calculate(Parameter.NODES,(Parameter.L / Parameter.NODES),children) ? You haven't included the code for Parameter so I have no idea where that comes from.

Comment: You are sending around mutable messages, and the code you show does not include mutation of global state (which I assume must happen in `environment`), which may well be the problem. Actors should not call methods outside of their lexical scope, unless they clearly “own” that code (i.e. are really the only caller) or that code is thread-safe.

Comment: @ViktorKlang: Sorry, I'm also new to posting questions here, but I've edited my post according to what you asked for.

Comment: @RolandKuhn: I'm not sure what you mean by "mutation of global state". The `Listener` is the only one calling `environment`. In there the two `ArrayBuffers` (old Population and offspring) are combined into one and some of the `Individuals` die according to some selection algorithm (so that the resulting `ArrayBuffer` will be the size of the old Population, including the "fittest" `Individuals` of the old population and children). I've included the code in my original post and I've tried putting that method into the `Listener` class, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Oh and the methods called in `environment` are also only called by `environment`.

Comment: With your first update it is clear that you never initialize `inds`. I guess you want it to start out as an empty ArrayBuffer instead of “no buffer”.